# JavaScript value plugged in with PHP returns error

Tags: javascript, php

I created a quiz timer which uses a combo of javascript and PHP. PHP get the quiz's end time from a URL parameter called `takingTest` and plugs it in the javaScript code. However, it does not work for everyone. It works for everyone if I plug in the value manually.  Any ideas what the problem is?

**The URL parameter**

[image]

I echoed the URL parameter using `<?php echo $_GET['takingTest']; ?>` and it showed the correct end time.

**Echoed value with PHP**

[image]

When it breaks, it returns a minus value and submits the quiz.

**Minus value example**

-10h -27m -225

My code looks like below:

```
<?php 

if(($_GET["started"]) === "true") {


?>  
<!--/*<!-- Quiz countdown block -->

    <script type="text/javascript" defer>

        $(function () {

// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $_GET['takingTest']; ?>").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
     $("#grader").trigger("click");
  }
}, 1000);

 });            


</script>

<?php } ?>
```

**Date Generation**

```
$defaultTimeZone = 'UTC';
if ( date_default_timezone_get() != $defaultTimeZone )date_default_timezone_set( $defaultTimeZone );

// somewhere in the code
function _date( $format = "r", $timestamp = false, $timezone = false ) {
    $userTimezone = new DateTimeZone( !empty( $timezone ) ? $timezone : 'GMT' );
    $gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone( 'GMT' );
    $myDateTime = new DateTime( ( $timestamp != false ? date( "r", ( int )$timestamp ) : date( "r" ) ), $gmtTimezone );
    $offset = $userTimezone->getOffset( $myDateTime );
    return date( $format, ( $timestamp != false ? ( int )$timestamp : $myDateTime->format( 'U' ) ) + $offset );
}


$time = new DateTime();

$time->add( new DateInterval( 'PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M' ) );


$stamp = $time->format( "F j, Y, g:i a" );

$_SESSION[ "EnddTime" ] = $stamp;
```

Comment: is it maybe just a timezone problem ? like the user is providing the start value but thats from a different time zone ?

Comment: or maybe someone found out that your pasing the test time per url and is trolling you :D

Comment: if you are providing the frontend code as well have the user give you the timestamp instead or at least convert it to an iso date before pushing it to the url

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I do not think it is the case of a troll as I am testing locally too.

Comment: @Emma as it currently is local Times probably wont help since the information of the time zone isnt passed in the parameter (and if its changeable Id jsut convert it to a timestmap which I find easier to handle )

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Timezone was passed in another file.

Comment: well I still think using timestamps is less likely to produce errors oO

Comment: @SleekGeek could you please add how you're generating the datetime in php?

Comment: @TimHinz I have added that. Thank you!

Comment: like jonathan has suggested, I still don't understand why you don't use timestamps.  It will provide several benefits. a) no time zone or date format issues, b) easier calculations and c) no converting back and forth... only convert to human-readable format when you want to display the date/time.

Answer (score 2):

### The Format issue:

So a couple things, first off is your date format. Alot of times if you use a invalid format it will work for MOST. That said the javascript one for the VAST majority of people is `D M d Y H:i:s O`. Another thing to consider in javascript and php is JS uses 0-11 for months while php uses 1-12.

### Better PHP and Timestamps:

Second thing is your php generation of a date function. It's way more complex than it needs to be. The best way to generate a javascript date from PHP is strtotime, though you need to multiply it by 1000 to convert it to milliseconds. It's also super easy to store in a database or wherever you need to and it's timezone independent being it's based around UTC.

In other words I say:

```
var countDownDate  = new Date(<?= echo strtotime($start_date)*1000; ?>);
```

Between those 2 options you should be able to fix it. I highly suggest the later as it should never fail unlike the first one.

and one more tip, if you use `<?= ?>` instead of `<?php ?>` you don't have to write echo.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for the PHP hint.

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard date format. `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Otherwise you're relying on the browser to parse it out and it may not behave as you expect. Month names, for example, may be different in different languages.

Also you might want to close the XSS vulnerability you have there.
`http://example.com/whatever.php?takingTest=");+alert('xss');+//`

Comment: I had the date format like that and still had the same issue. I changed it around when I was looking for solutions. However, I will change it back to see what happens. More importantly, I will learn how to close XSS vulnerability.